# Getting Mockito to work with RoboGuice and Robolectric

Tags: android, testing, mockito, robolectric, roboguice

I am nearly desperate getting Mockito to work in conjunction with RoboGuice and Robolectric.

I have a gradle multiproject which includes an Android app which is designed with RoboGuice. Now I have a test case in which I want to override the default Robuguice modul in order to inject some mocks. But sadly I can not get it working.

Here is my approach so far:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class NetworkUtilTest {

    @Inject
    private NetworkUtil networkUtil;

    private ErrorDialog errorDialog = mock(ErrorDialog.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);

    private FragmentActivity activity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().get();
                RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector(Robolectric.application, RoboGuice.DEFAULT_STAGE, Modules.override(RoboGuice.newDefaultRoboModule(Robolectric.application)).with(new MyTestModule()));

        RoboInjector injector = RoboGuice.getInjector(activity);
        injector.injectMembersWithoutViews(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testNetworkInfoNull() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) Robolectric.application.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ShadowConnectivityManager shadowConnectivityManager = shadowOf(manager);
        shadowConnectivityManager.setActiveNetworkInfo(null);

        networkUtil.isNetworkAvailable();

        verify(errorDialog).show(R.string.network_error);
    }

    private class MyTestModule extends AbstractModule {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(ErrorDialog.class).toInstance(errorDialog);
        }
    }
}
```

Many instructions are using 
    RoboGuice.getInjector(Robolectric.application)
but I got tests without the binding of a mock to work with my approach above. So it seems to be the right way?

If I run the test I got the following error:

```
1) null returned by binding at roboguice.config.DefaultRoboModule.configure(DefaultRoboModule.java:131)
        but roboguice.inject.FragmentManagerProvider.activity is not @Nullable
while locating roboguice.inject.NullProvider<android.app.Activity>
        at roboguice.config.DefaultRoboModule.configure(DefaultRoboModule.java:131)
        while locating android.app.Activity
        for field at roboguice.inject.FragmentManagerProvider.activity(Unknown Source)
        at roboguice.inject.FragmentManagerProvider.class(Unknown Source)
        while locating roboguice.inject.FragmentManagerProvider
        while locating android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
        for field at com.example.test.dialog.ErrorDialog.fragmentManager(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.test.util.NetworkUtilTest$MyTestModule.configure(NetworkUtilTest.java:80)

        1 error
        com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

        1) null returned by binding at roboguice.config.DefaultRoboModule.configure(DefaultRoboModule.java:131)
        but roboguice.inject.FragmentManagerProvider.activity is not @Nullable
while locating roboguice.inject.NullProvider<android.app.Activity>
        at roboguice.config.DefaultRoboModule.configure(DefaultRoboModule.java:131)
        while locating android.app.Activity
        for field at roboguice.inject.FragmentManagerProvider.activity(Unknown Source)
        at roboguice.inject.FragmentManagerProvider.class(Unknown Source)
        while locating roboguice.inject.FragmentManagerProvider
        while locating android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
        for field at com.example.test.dialog.ErrorDialog.fragmentManager(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.test.util.NetworkUtilTest$MyTestModule.configure(NetworkUtilTest.java:80)

        1 error
        at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:435)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:175)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:109)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:83)
        at roboguice.RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector(RoboGuice.java:94)
        at com.example.test.util.NetworkUtilTest.setUp(NetworkUtilTest.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
        at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:250)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at $Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:355)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Does anybody know a solution for this problem? There are many guides for advanced Android testing with Mockito, RoboGuice and Robolectric, so I think that is has to work?

I already took a look at the astroboy examples, but it did not get me further.

Regards
Tobias

Comment: Yes, this should work but it is a bit complex to setup. Can you try to swap activity and baseApplicationInjector creation ?

Comment: I've developed a custom subclass of RobolectricTestRunner that may suit your needs. The test runner scans for fields annotated with @Mock in your test and automatically binds them so that they may be injected into your activity under test.  There are other features as well, but I think that it may get you what you need. Link to the github project: https://github.com/jeske717/injected-test-runner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers!
I finally fixed it by adding the following line to my test module:

```
bind(FragmentManager.class).toInstance(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
```

Then the tests run successfully. I hope that there are no additional problems. I wasted enough time :-)